# Getting DXGI swapchain by HWND

Tags: c++, directx, gdi+, rdp, dxgi

There is a simple application which works as a manager of MS RDP sessions. You open RDP sessions to different computers and then you can see their previews in a common monitoring panel.

An OLE control is used to organize an RDP session.

```
CWnd::CreateControl(CLSID_MsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting, ....
```

Previously I just copied RDP window via PrintWindow and then showed it on the preview.

```
PrintWindow(hWnd, hCompatibleDC,0);
```

In Windows 10 it does not work. Microsoft Spy++ shows the following picture

```
Window "Output Painter Window" OPContainerClass
   Window "Output Painter Child Window" OPWindowClass (Invisible)
   Window "Output Painter DX Child Window" OPWindowClass
```

On older Windows "Output Painter Child Window" is mainly visible and in this case PrintWindow works.

Also on Windows 10, RDP does not work at all if I remove DXGI.dll. So I believe that PrintWindow does not work because RDP uses DirectX to draw the window content.

I thought about DirectX function hooking to get the picture but it looks ridiculous. It is a big overhead. I can control the application entirely. I can access the RDP OPWindowClass HWNDs. I can even control them via ShowWindow, etc.

Is there any way to get DirectX objects (like IDXGISwapChain1 or ID2D1HwndRenderTarget) which are connected to HWND?

Comment: You still need to hook DX CreateSwapChain function(s) and from there figure out the HWND and keep a map of swapchain->HWNDs.

Comment: @VuVirt, yes it was my first idea but it is a big overhead. I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: I don't think you have any other options. I've been involved in such projects and it is definetly doable with hooks and not at all a big overhead.

Comment: there is problem because you cannot hook 32bit and 64bit in one process.

Comment: @Eugen Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @tunafish24, yes, I did. I am sorry for the delayed reply. Please see my answer below and the github project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a documented API to solve the issue. So, I hook the **IDXGISwapChain::Present** method and capture the black box window frames.

It is important to remember that in **DirectX 11** when you capture the frames, you have to use the same DirectX device and device context object which were used to create the swap chain. It is possible.

In **DirectX 12** it is difficult to get the current frame which is just being presented. So, I capture the one which was previously presented. For me, it is not a big issue.

The **DirectX 11** hook algorithm is

```
// Create a sample window.
...

// Create a swap chain for that window.
...

// Get the swap chain pointer.
// I do it via a DirectX helper class.
std::uintptr_t* swapChainPointer =
   static_cast<std::uintptr_t*>(static_cast<void*>
   (d3d11Helper.GetSwapChain()));

// Get the virtual table pointer.
std::uintptr_t* virtualTablePointer =
   reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t*>(swapChainPointer[0]);

// Get the "Present" method pointer.
// "Present" has index 8 because:
// - "Present" is the first original virtual method of IDXGISwapChain.
// - IDXGISwapChain is based on IDXGIDeviceSubObject
//   which has 1 original virtual method (GetDevice).
// - IDXGIDeviceSubObject is based on IDXGIObject
//   which has 4 original virtual methods (SetPrivateData,..).
// - IDXGIObject is based on IUnknown
//   which has 3 original virtual methods (QueryInterface, ...). 
// So, 0 + 1 + 4 + 3 = 8.
presentPointer_ = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(virtualTablePointer[8]);

// Use the **MinHook** or **PolyHook 2** library
// to hook the method with a trampoline.
...
```

The **DirectX 11** frame capture algorithm is

```
// Get the swap chain DirectX 11 device.
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> d3d11Device;
hr = swapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), &d3d11Device);

// Also, get the device context.
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> d3d11DeviceContext;
d3d11Device->GetImmediateContext(&d3d11DeviceContext);

// Get the swap chain texture.
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> d3d11SwapChainTexture;
hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),
  &d3d11SwapChainTexture);

// Then you can create texture
// (staging texture if you want to copy from the GPU to the CPU).
...

// Copy the frame.
// Here, the destination is a staging texture.
d3d11DeviceContext->CopyResource(d3d11StagingTexture.Get(),
  d3d11SwapChainTexture.Get());

// Access the data from the CPU.
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedSubresource;
UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
hr = d3d11DeviceContext->Map(d3d11StagingTexture.Get(), subresource,
  D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &mappedSubresource);
```

See the **DirectX 12** hook algorithm highlights below.

```
// Overall, the algorithm is similar to the DirectX 11 one
// but you also need the command queue which was used to
// create the black box window swap chain.
// The simplest way is to find the offset from the swap chain
// object start when you create a sample swap chain.

std::uintptr_t i = 0;
const char* start = static_cast<char*>(
    static_cast<void*>(d3d12Helper.GetSwapChain()));
while (true) {
  if (reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(d3d12Helper.GetCommandQueue()) ==
      *static_cast<const std::uintptr_t*>(
        static_cast<const void*>(start + i))) {
    commandQueueOffset_ = i;
    break;
  }
  ++i;
}
```

See the **DirectX 12** capture algorithm highlights below.

```
// You need a readback resource property
// to get the frame from the GPU to CPU.  
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> readbackResource_;


if (readbackResource_.Get()) {

  // If you are here, then the capture method was already called.

  // If the pointer is nullptr, map it. With DirectX 12,
  // it is not necessary to unmap it between frames.    
  if (readbackData_ == nullptr) {
    hr = readbackResource_->Map(0, nullptr, &readbackData_);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(readbackData_)
  // UINT frameRowPitch = readbackDataPitch_;
  // UINT frameWidth = frameRowPitch / 4;
  // UINT frameHeight = readbackDataHeight_;

} else {

   // Create the read back resource
   ...
}

// Initialize the copying of the swap chain resource
// to your read back resource.
...

// Just find the command queue object.
const char* start = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*( 
  swapChain3.Get()));
ID3D12CommandQueue* commandQueue =
  reinterpret_cast<ID3D12CommandQueue*>(
    *static_cast<const std::uintptr_t*>(
      static_cast<const void*>(start + commandQueueOffset_)));

// ... then execute the command list
// to copy the swap chain texture to the read back texture.
ID3D12CommandList* commandLists[] = {copyCommandList.Get()};
commandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(ARRAYSIZE(commandLists), commandLists);

// The read back texture does not contain the correct picture yet!
// You will get it when the capture method is called next time.
```

Please, see and star the full example project here: https://github.com/eugen15/directx-present-hook

Do not hesitate to contact me if you have any questions!